# How to configure VPN + Tor + linux as a proxy server?

Tags: proxy, ip, anonymity, tor

### Goal

To hide the IP address using Tor, which goes through a proxy server to make HTTP/FTP requests look like they came from a regular user, not one who uses Tor.

## Example

A user requests the website. The request goes through the user's VPN, which then goes through Tor, which connects to a proxy server that finally makes request to the websiteA.

### Problem

How to put the proxy server after the Tor? As far as I know, this is not possible with standard configuration of a client machine.

### Possible solution

I came up with an idea, which is to intercept all requests on the client machine and send them via Tor to the web server.

1. User requests https://websiteA.com
2. My software or user machine configuration takes the request address and sends it via Tor to the web server:
   https://myproxy.com?resource=https://websiteA.com
3. The server gets response and returns it to the Tor network and then to the client machine.

### Question

Is my proposed solution viable? Is there a better or simpler solution to achieve the goal?

If I must stick to my solution, what are possible obstacles? (user authentication, POST requests, FTP protocol, etc.)

Comment: You can run Tor over VPN or VPN over Tor. Neither makes much sense, and I fail to see the novelty in your solution.

Comment: VPN over TOR is useful for connecting to sites through TOR, when those sites are known to block connections from TOR.

Comment: This solution is too convoluted to do any good. You use VPN to access Tor only if your ISP does not allow connecting to Tor. And you would use Tor to access the proxy only to hide your own IP from the proxy. If you don't have to hide from the proxy, connect direct to it.

Comment: @thoriumBR, I need to hide the IP from the proxy.

Comment: And why use both VPN and Tor? Only one is enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier solution. One can use a tool like Proxifier to set up a proxy chain.

1. Add Tor as a proxy into the chain
2. Then add any other proxy

To hide Tor from your ISP, use VPN or add another proxy in front of the Tor proxy in the proxy chain.